# What is the meaning of ごちそうになってこうかな?

Tags: meaning

> 「じきに夕食の支度もできると思いますよ。
>   　どうです、いっしょに？」
>
> 「ラッキー！
>   　それじゃ、ごちそうになってこうかな。」

My attempt - So, it's your treat then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nuance is more like "I guess I'll take you up on that offer."

ごちそうになる is the standard polite expression for eating a meal that was prepared by someone else or at someone else's expense, and it includes an element of gratitude for the favour (similar to ～ていただく forms). The form ～てこう is a contraction of ～て行こう, ie. "I'll do X before I go", and the かな introduces a slight uncertainty, as in a "maybe" or "I guess". So the full ごちそうになってこうかな literally means something like "maybe I'll eat here (gratefully, at your expense) before I leave".

"So, it's your treat then?" doesn't really work as a translation because there's nothing in the response that's questioning the first speaker's intent. The first speaker has already made a clear offer to provide a meal, and the second speaker is simply accepting with an "Oh, nice! I guess I'll do that, then."

Comment: Could ～てこう be a contradiction of ～て置こう or it would be ～とこう?

Comment: As you say, ～ておこう would usually be ～とこう. I think ～て行こう fits better in this circumstance either way, because the implication seems to be that the second speaker was going to leave, but since they've been invited to join the first speaker for a meal they'll stay a little longer before doing so.